# Consolidating DOM queries and file_get_contents

Tags: php, dom, xpath, simple-html-dom

I have researched this quite a bit over the last few days, and I have found all the answers online for the various functions, so thank you.

I now have 3 separate bits of code that all grab the contents of a webpage (the page would be an e-commerce product page, review page, something with a product on it) to get different information, but I am assuming this is very inefficient grabbing the contents 3 times!

The 3 bits of code do the 3 following things:
1) Get the webpage Title
2) Get all the images from a page
3) Find figures to get (what is hopefully) the price of the item on that page.

I would appreciate some help to group these together so it only has to get the file contents once. This is my current code:
1st Time:

```
function getDetails($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        //preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        //The above didnt work well enough (for getting Title when <title id=... > etc) so used the DOM below



            preg_match("/(\£[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/",$str,$price); //£ for GBP
            $priceRes = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price[0]);

            //$pageDeatil[0]=$title;
            $pageDeatil[1]=$priceRes;
            return $pageDeatil;

    }
}

$pageDeatil = getDetails("$newItem_URL");
//$itemTitle = $pageDeatil[0];
$itemPrice = $pageDeatil[1];
```

2nd Time:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("$newItem_URL");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$itemTitle = $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue."\n";
```

3rd Time:

```
include('../../code/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
include('../../code/url_to_absolute/url_to_absolute.php');

$html = file_get_html($newItem_URL);
foreach($html->find('img') as $e){

$imgURL =  url_to_absolute($url, $e->src);
    //More code here

}
```

I cant seem to get the file once then use just that throughout the rest. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using cURL when scraping sites. Your price fetching code doesn't seem to be particularly efficient either, I think you should use XPath there as well.
The return of the function could be an object with price, title and an array of images.

```
function get_details($url) {
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

   $html = curl_exec($ch);

   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   @$dom->loadHTML($html);
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

   $product         = new stdClass;
   $product->title  = $xpath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $product->price  = // price query goes here
   $product->images = array();

   foreach($xpath->query('//img') as $image) {
      $product->images[] = $image->getAttribute('src');
   }

   return $product;
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know how it works out, thank you. Not sure about using XPath for getting the prices, as the price will be in various places on different sites and Im not sure how I would go about this at the moment.

Comment: You should create mini modules for each site, and make super-specific XPath queries that retrieve the price accurately every time. Let me know if you need any help. I'm a bit of an expert when it comes to XPath lol :)